# Role of dependencies while installing software??

Tags: dependencies, vlc, video-player

What is the role of dependencies while installing any software?I was installing `vlc player` and it were closed by giving me error something like `check dependency` .

What is to solution of this and how i'll get these dependencies??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install VLC player, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

As far as Package Dependencies:

> Programs often use some of the same files as each other. Rather than
>   putting these files into each package, a separate package can be
>   installed to provide them for all of the programs that need them. So,
>   to install a program which needs one of these files, the package
>   containing those files must also be installed. When a package depends
>   on another in this way, it is known as a package dependency. By
>   specifying dependencies, packages can be made smaller and simpler, and
>   duplicates of files and programs are mostly removed.
>
> When you install a program, its dependencies must be installed at the
>   same time. Usually, most of the required dependencies will already be
>   installed, but a few extras may be needed, too. So, when you install a
>   package, don't be surprised if several other packages are installed
>   too - these are just dependencies which are needed for your chosen
>   package to function properly.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware)</sup>

If you have  .tar.gz file of VLC and you want to install, you just have to extract the file then compile from source.

```
tar -jxvf filename.tar.bz2
```

This will create a folder in the same folder you extracted it, then you will have to compile it

```
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Comment: if i am having .tar.gz file of vlc then how to install? Because i am not having internet connection so i want to install the vlc player offline..

Comment: I've updated the answer with that info.

Comment: in make only it was showing that dependency problem..

Comment: Then try it the other way.  I've added `sudo` before the last commands, you can try it as well.

Comment: `make` will not work without `root` permissions,so i also done with this option..but maybe some other problem like ,`vlc may need some package but that package will not be there in my library`,so i will try to do it by using internet.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help..i want to know that there are some scrip files and some c files also,so it was searching for ncurse.c and pncurse.c file which are not there,so i think that it will be giving error for dependency of ncurse package.